# how to get Visual Studio to show formatted color for iOS Xcode .m files

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I want to use Microsoft Visual Studio to edit my iOS (iPhone/iPad) Xcode .m objective-C files.

How do I set VS to treat a .m file like a .c file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found how to do it:

Step...
1.  Visual Studio 2010 & 2013: Tools -> Options -> TextEditor -> File Extensions 
2.  Type 'm' into Extension field, 
3.  field "Editor:" = Microsoft Visual C++, 
4.  press "Add", 
5.  OK, 
6.  close and re-open your .m file